# Combining two lists of ints, into one list of strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Edit: I've realized my error (if statement, variable x is assigned to element in string and i'm comparing to length of list).. Trying to resolve that tomorrow morning. Appologies for the stupid error but i would appreciate any bits of learning.

I'm trying to combine two lists into a single list.

```
 m = [1,2,3]
 n = [4,5,6]
 v = m+n

 def myFun():
   return [(str(x)+str(y)) for x in m if x < len(m) for y in n if y < len(n)]

 print(myFun())
```

the result of myFun() should display "14, 25, 36"

i also tried to breakdown the code into a more pythonic world and have seen where i've gone astray:

```
 def my(fun()):
   for x in m if x < len(m):
     for y in n if y < len(n): # problem here, running until count 9 instead of 3
                               # like it's supposed to.. author error.. 
       newlist.append(str(x)+str(y))
   print(newlist)
```

Am i even headed in the right direction or should i be trying to build a map, i've seen a few pages saying that maps could be counter-productive if you have to reverse with a list-comp or lambda? Also, is it possible to count a specific object inside a list comprehension / lambda? (e.g. list length)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `zip()`:

```
In [8]: m = [1,2,3]

In [9]: n = [4,5,6]

In [10]: [str(x)+str(y) for x,y in zip(m,n)]
Out[10]: ['14', '25', '36']
```

or use `itertools.izip_longest()` if the lists are of different lengths:

```
In [2]: m=[1,2,3]

In [3]: n=[4,5,6,7]

In [4]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [5]: [str(x)+str(y) for x,y in izip_longest(m,n,fillvalue="")]
Out[5]: ['14', '25', '36', '7']
```

Comment: could you explain the purpose of in[] / out[]?

Comment: @KyleKearney these are coming because I use `IPython` shell, these are similar to `>>>` of default python shell.

Answer (score 3):

use map:

```
map(lambda a, b: str(a) + str(b), m, n)
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary But to be fair, neither will your answer with `zip` :) [Well, `zip` will "fail" silently - at least `map` will break]

Comment: @JonClements map will print something like `None7` if `n =[4,5,6,7]`. I think `izip_longest()` will be the best choice.

Comment: I was thinking: `', '.join('{}{}'.format(*nums) for nums in izip_longest(m, n, fillvalue=''))`

Comment: @Jon, ironically that seemed to make more sense than zip / map / etc.. I better get back to learning! :S